# String Format Issue

Tags: string, c#-2.0

I've got the following method:

```
public static string ReturnFormat(string input, int maxLength, int decimalPrecision, char formatChar)
  {
   string[] format = new string[2];
   string[] inputs = new string[2];

   inputs = input.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);

   if (input.Length > maxLength)
   {
    int offset = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    if (inputs[0].Length > maxLength - (1 + decimalPrecision))
    {
     offset = maxLength - (1 + decimalPrecision);
    }
    else
     offset = inputs[0].Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++)
    {
     format[0] += formatChar;

     if (counter < decimalPrecision)
     {
      format[1] += '0';
      counter++;
     }
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("{0:" + format[0] + "." + format[1] + "}");
    return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:" + format[0] + "." + format[1] + "}", input);
   }
   else
    return input;
  }
```

Which say I'm using as:

```
ReturnFormat("12.3456789011243", 10, 2, '#') // format is {0:##.00} // output 12.3456789011243
ReturnFormat("12345678901.1243", 10, 2, '#') // format is {0:#######.00} // output 12345678901.1243
```

Now my issue is that the input string is not formatted well, still the format strig appears to be ok.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The output I would like to be 1234568.12

Comment: Also, this is a very strange format function and I'm having a hard time figuring out when this would be wanted.

Comment: This will be wanted for displaying a result in a TextBox and that TextBox it's rather small and the result will not fit user's visual range. I mean the TextBox can store huge values, but the user will not be able to see the proper result and also the textbox is readonly.

Comment: Then I would recommend you to remove the decimals before you even start shorting the integer part. I think this way of shortening will be very confusing for the users and actually plain wrong.

Comment: Ok so basically I'm working on a converter, and I have a option regarding digital precision. When I convert from unit A to unit B the result is something like 12345678901.1243

Now if the precision setting is set to 2, the converted value should contain a max of 2 digits.

In my case the number being 12345678901.1243 that would mean 1234567890 and no values after the NumberDecimalSeparator. That will be a right, so only values like 12.3456789011243 will be processed to 12.35) Sorry about my english. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right.

Comment: Your english is fine but I still do not understand. "Now if the precision setting is set to 2, the converted value should contain a max of 2 digits." - digits or decimals places? Either way, neither explains why 12345678901.1243 should become 1234567890.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is a String not a Double, so it gets formatted like a string: the formatting does not know about decimal places in that case.

You could use `Double.Parse()` to transform the string into a Double value, but take care of using the right culture.

Another thing, is there a specific reason for not using the more natural format {0:0.00} in both cases? If you really mean to use a placeholder for digits then # is ok, otherwise 0 is best.

Tested solution (beware it truncates and does not round) I needed some time to understand what was actually wanted:

```
public static string ReturnFormat(string input, int maxLength, int decimalPrecision)
{
    if (input.Length <= maxLength)
        return input;
    Char separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
    string[] inputs = input.Split(separator);
    // NB: truncating rather than rounding
    if (inputs[1].Length > decimalPrecision)
        inputs[1] = inputs[1].Substring(0, decimalPrecision);
    int digits = (maxLength - decimalPrecision - 1);
    // NB: truncating rather than rounding, adding ~ to signalize the
    // presence of missing significant digits
    if (inputs[0].Length > digits)
        inputs[0] = inputs[0].Substring(0, digits-1) + "~";
    return inputs[0] + separator + inputs[1];
}
```

Comment: OK,

So I've used Double.Parse() and it works ok in 1st case (12.3456789011243 returns 12.35) but doesn't work proper on 2nd (12345678901.1243 returns the same)

Still, the format is ok i guess ( {0:#######.00} ) in the 2nd case.

Comment: # are placeholders, it is a pitfall, see my cheat sheet on http://color-of-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58:c-format-strings&catid=38:programming&Itemid=66

Comment: Do not hesitate to contact me for other questions or comments regarding formatting, I try to keep that sheet up-to-date. I think you will be happier with 0.00 as a format string instead of doing that complicated format string computation.

Comment: The thing is that i need to display a value at a fixed length and that's why I'm trying to use this. Since it's a must in my case to display a value at fixed length I can't use 0.00 :(

Comment: Are you aware that you essentially are changing the value but still keeps the decimals? It looks fishy.

Comment: Fishy or not, I would rather use a `Regex.Replace` in your case with a `(\d{n})\d*\.(\d+)` and replace with \1~.\2 for example using ~ to signalize that significant digits are missing to remove a bit of the fishy taste :-)

Comment: I made an edit to provide some working code with another way to solve your problem I hope. I neeeded some time to understand your goal. Hope it helps.